# How can I take the dot product of multiple vectors in a numpy array all at once?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I have an array in python:

```
testarray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5),[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15])
```

With this array, I want to take the dot product of the first vector and the rest so 1,2,3,4,5 = 1 with the second vector and the third.  I will implement this numerical value into an equation later as well.

How can I do this? take the dot product of the first vector and every other single vector in my numpy array?

If I have 3 vectors like I do in my example, then I should have 3 different numbers. Is it also possible to have python show me which of the vectors it is taking the dot product of?

Comment: Add the script to your question.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you seek the dot product for any combination of two vectors from your list?

Comment: Clearly list the expected output for the sample?

Comment: can you elaborate more on "take the dot product of the first vector and every other single vector in my numpy array?"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the dot product for every combination of two vectors from your list, you can use `itertools.combinations`.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
>>> [x.dot(y) for x, y in itertools.combinations(a, 2)]
[130, 205, 530]
```

If you also want the indices of the vectors, combine that with `enumerate`:

```
>>> [(i, k, x.dot(y)) for (i, x), (k, y) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(a), 2)]
[(0, 1, 130), (0, 2, 205), (1, 2, 530)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your result by calculating the dot product between arrays of shape (5,) and (5,2) or (2,5) and (5,). Remember that to multiply matrices of mxn and pxq, you need to have n==p. So, in numpy:

```
In [38]: np.dot(testarray[0], testarray[1:].T)
Out[38]: array([130, 205])
In [39]: np.dot(testarray[1:], testarray[0])
Out[39]: array([130, 205])
```

This avoids cycling over arrays in python, which is slow (but negligible for just 2 elements in your example)

If you need the dot product of your vector with itself, do it this way:

```
In [40]: np.dot(testarray[0], testarray.T)
Out[40]: array([ 55, 130, 205])
```

The result of the dot product is ordered. First vector with first, then second, then third.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the dot product between a pair of the first vector and all the other vectors one by one:

```
import numpy as np

testArray = ([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15])
dotProducts = np.array([])

for eachVector in range(1, len(testArray)):
    dotProducts = np.append(dotProducts, np.dot(testArray[0], testArray[eachVector]))
```

create an empty array for your dot products, iterate through all vectors inside your array except the first one, and calculate dotproducts, and then append it to your dotProduct array

there are two elements in the dotProduct result if you want to calculate between the first one and every other one. if you include the first vector too:

```
for eachVector in range(len(testArray)):
```

then you will have three elements